# C++ Data file with an unwanted character: How to remove rogue character and calculate mean, standard deviation and standard error

Tags: c++

I have a data file which contains 49 numbers + 1 word and another file that contains 50 numbers. My task is to compute the mean, standard deviation and standard error for both. At the moment I have a code which will happily compute the correct values for the file containing only numbers.  How do I remove the character?

I a beginner and unsure how to correctly use the getline() function to put data from the file into a string and then somehow use cin.ignore() and cin.clear() to remove the character? Help would be appreciated!

Program:

```
// Assignment 2: Milikan data programme
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>


using namespace std;
//Mean function
double mean(double *mydata, double N)
{ 
    double sum(0), m;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        sum += mydata[i];
    }
    m = (sum/(double)N);
    return(m);
}
//Standard deviation function
double standard_dev(double *mydata, double m, int N)
{
    double *mydata2 = new double[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        mydata2[i] = pow((mydata[i]-m), 2);
    }
    double sum(0), S, X;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        sum += mydata2[i];
    }
    X = sum/(N-1);
    S = sqrt(X);
    return (S);
}

int main ()
{
    int N(0);
    char filename[100];
    double m, sterr, stdev;
    string temp;

    cout<<"Please enter the number of data points:  ";
    cin>> N;
    cout<<"Please enter the name of the file:  ";
    cin>>filename;

    //Dynamic memory allocation for N data points in array mydata
    double *mydata;
    mydata = new double[N];

    //Open file and attach chosen file to myfile
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(filename);

    //Check it opened sucessfully 
    if(!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cerr<<"\nError: file could not be opened!"<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return(1);
    }

    //Detect and ignore rogue character???


    //Read data from the file into an array
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        myfile>>mydata[i];          
    }


    m = mean(mydata, N);                                                                   
    stdev = standard_dev(mydata, m, N); 
    sterr = 1/stdev;

    cout<<"\nThe mean charge of an electron is  : "<<m<<" eV"<<endl; /
    cout<<"The standard deviation of results is : "<<stdev<<endl;
    cout<<"The standard error of results is : "<<sterr<<endl;

    myfile.close();     //Close file
    delete[] mydata;    // Free memory
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is each number on a separate line? Is the unwanted character or string on a separate line as well?

Comment: Please don't put the file in a comment, instead put an excerpt of it in the question.

Comment: 1.64638 error 1.55023 1.54612 1.54004  ect....

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that the stream objects `failbit` becomes set if the extraction of a number fails. You can check for that, and if set you skip all non-digit characters in the stream until you see a digit again.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
while (myfile)
{
    myfile >> value;

    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        clear_failbit();

        while (next_character_is_not_digit())
            get_and_discard_next_character();
    }
}
```

Of course, a better solution would probably be to *not* generate files containing errors.